# "It was on Thursday" or "It was Thursday"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, difference

I am writing an essay. In the introduction, I wrote

> It was Tuesday.

meaning the day was Tuesday. I am describing the setting of a story. The story didn't start yet.

An alternative

> It was **on** Thursday.

popped up and I wonder if which one is correct and whether both could be used in the given context. The second sentence seems to have the notion of *it* as if *it* has been introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given context

> It was Tuesday

is more suitable. As you are beginning the story and nothing has been introduced it is correct, the second would be more appropriate where something has been introduced.

For example:

> I really liked that party we went to! It was on Thursday.